# Form validation without form tag on input - Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, tags

I have popup component in which I want to insert form validation on input element for name (required field and minlength 3 characters).
Is is possible to do it without setting up complete code in form tag?

```
<div class="scenario-div">
<label style="font-size: 1.4rem; font-weight: 400; margin-bottom: 10px;">{{context.header}}</label>
<div class="" style="width: 90%; margin-bottom: 10px; align-self: center;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <label style="font-size: 1.2rem; font-weight: 500;">Name</label>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="context.name" placeholder="enter Name" style="color: #569bd2; margin: 0px; width: 50%" minlength="3" required/>

            <select *ngIf="context.showOptionDropdown" class="custom-select-project" style="width:50%" #optionSelect (change)="context.option.value">
                <option disabled>Select type</option>
                <option value="option1">option1</option>
                <option value="option2">option2</option>
                <option value="option3">option3</option>
                <option value="option4">option4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin-bottom: 10px;" *ngIf="!context.hideDescription">
        <label style="font-size: 1.2rem; font-weight: 400;">Description</label>
        <textarea rows="4" [(ngModel)]="context.description" cols="50" maxlength="250" placeholder="Enter text here" style="color: #569bd2; resize: none; font-weight: 400; font-size: 1.2rem;"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div>   
    <button class="btn-main" (click)="confirm(context)" style="width: 15%;">Confirm</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Validation' based on ngModel

```
    <input type="text" required name="title" [(ngModel)]="titleModel">
    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="titleModel?.length > 10">
          10 max
    </span>
    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="!titleModel">
          required
    </span>
    <button [disabled]="titleModel?.length > 10 || !titleModel">OK</button>
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/PvmMp17dDTlqedkBegdv?p=preview)

---

'Validation' based on local template variable:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)='0' #title>
<span style="color:red" *ngIf="title.value.length > 10">
      10 max
</span>
<span style="color:red" *ngIf="!title.value">
      required
</span>

<button [disabled]="title.value.length > 10 || !title.value">OK</button>
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/lxqoCPXGnV1D6t4UwTtL?p=preview)

Comment: Ok, I got it and creating spans for value.length works fine, but I still am able to do submitt ... I need to lock submit if my length is less then 3 characters.

Comment: I don't see any form tag in your snippet

Comment: But there is none ...That is the question ...How can I do form validation, but without form tag. However, thaks to you, i can manage to hide submit button until user enters more than 3 characters :)

Comment: If there is no form how do you have submit? You mean an action on a plain button? Then, you hide the button based on the condition or check in the class for the model/value length with if-else

Comment: Yes, click action that triggers submit, so now works like charm with ngIf and length

Comment: Sorry ...my bad ...had some editing on question...will fix it now

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `FormControl` from the reactive forms API, which can be used with a standalone `<input>` that's not wrapped into a `<form>` tag.

```
Component({
   ...
   template: `<input type="text" [formControl]="name">` 
})
class MyComponent {
  name = new FormControl('',
           [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);
}
```